# Doing a task until there's no exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I'm just doing a simple program and it needs read an integer
So there will be a NumberFormatException if the user enter something other than integer
So i want to keep asking for the intger until this exception doesnt occur..

```
try{
    num=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println("Enter a valid number");
    //do this again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  while (true) {
    try {
      String input = br.readLine();
      int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
      System.out.println("You entered: "+num);
      break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Enter a valid number");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code about a while loop, like this:

```
  boolean valid = false;
  while(!valid) {
  try{
       num=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
       valid = true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Enter a valid number");
        valid = false;
        //do this again
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getUserInput() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
    try {
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);
        getUserInput();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Here I'm recursively calling the function after getting a valid input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getUserInput();
}
```